# Form_for with radio_button generated from database

Tags: forms, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

This would seem easy to do, basically I'm using Devise for administrative purposes, so every user signing up can create a product/figure linked to their account then put up that product for a trade with another user.

```
Class User
  rolify
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :trades
  has_many :figures, :through => :trades
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trades

Class Figure
  attr_accessible :image_url, :name, :series, :figure_id

  has_many :trades
  has_many :users, :through => :trades
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trades

Class Trade
  attr_accessible :figure_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :figure
```

The Controller for Trade

```
def new
  @trade = Trade.new
end

def create
  @trade = current_user.figures.build(params[:trade])
end
```

The Form for trade

```
<%= form_for(@trade) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <% Figure.all.each do |figure| %>
      # Create a list of figurines radio buttons
      <%= f.radio_button :figure_id, figure.id, :checked => (params[:figure_id] == nil ? false : params[:figure_id]) %>
        # Link the figures thumbnail to the radio button
      <%= f.label :figure_id, image_tag(figure.image_url, :size => "40x58", :alt => figure.name ), :value => "#{figure.id}" %>
   <% end %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"lo+RWOLxGhPIP1pmJhk9v+vetO7cGEKGY844egaQ6A0=",
  "trade"=>{"figure_id"=>"12"},
  "commit"=>"Create Trade"}
```

Here's the problem I'm getting: **unknown attribute: figure_id**

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this error should go away if you build a `Trade` instead of a `Figure` (you're just trying to link a figure to a user through a new trade, right?):

```
def create
   @trade = current_user.trades.build(params[:trade])
   @trade.save
end
```